# QGIS - Struggling with r.reclass, North must be larger than south, etc - error log in post

Tags: qgis, raster

I'm currently in between ArcMap licenses so I'm working through QGIS and trying to reclassify a land use Raster from the USDA with 256 values. I have a text file I'm trying to use as the input: [image: shown here]

Here is the symbology tab of my raster, let me know if you need to view different aspects of it. I should also note I can't find an attribute table for the raster, so for all I know, it has to do with that. [image: raster details]

Here are my parameters, pretty basic stuff: [image: parameters]

I'm trying to run this in the r.reclass tool in GRASSGIS but I'm getting some errors shown here: [image: Errors]

From what I can tell, it accepts my rules when I enter them as text rather than upload them as a file, but I'm still getting an error when I try to run the script.

EDIT: After fixing the north larger than south, I'm still getting other errors - log  [here](https://pastebin.com/cR8LKYRQ)

Comment: Just about the **ERROR: North must be larger than South** let me draw your attention to the region extent (the last picture) `n 0.0 s 0.0 e 0.0 w 0.0`. Perhaps you can check **Advanced parameters** - GRASS GIS 7 region extent; Select `Use layer extent` and see what happens.

Comment: @Kazuhito That took care of that error, but [still getting others](https://imgur.com/a/9jF4pyb)

Comment: EJSMIZ, glad it worked (a bit :) The other error says the reclassify rule is invalid. Not sure, but a common format is `6 thru 12 = 9`. BTW you may be better off with **r.recode**.

Comment: @Kazuhito I went and tried a different table [here](https://imgur.com/TYiYjvY) but it said I didn't specify any rules when I tried to run it..

Comment: EJSMIZ, how did it go? Could doubled 8 be troublesome?

Comment: @Kazuhito it didn't work, the official [grassgis tutorial](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/r.reclass.html) has a format similar to what I'm doing with double numbers in some places.

Comment: EJSMIZ, I see. What do you see in the latest error message? At least `* = NoData - invalid reclass rule` would have gone, as you now have `* = 9` instead.

Comment: I am quite sure you could just skip using grass and use the QGIS raster calculator to do what you want. It is very simple to use

Comment: @Kazuhito [it got even worse](https://imgur.com/a/7yIqvRK) every time I run r.reclass, it just crashes right when it gets to this line. When I try r.recode, I get [this](https://imgur.com/a/py9LJE9)

Comment: EJSMIZ, too bad. This may be QGIS 3.4 issues. About **r.recode** the rule format is different (sorry... I should have mentioned earlier). In using either tool QGIS 2.18  is probably safer. Good luck.

Comment: @Kazuhito same crashy business with Las Palmas, will try to write out proper syntax for r.recode later.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a simpler Reclassify tool, search in the toolbox for "Reclassify by table". This native reclassification algorithm is much simpler to execute than the GRASS based algorithm.